# Changing DropDownListFor Data in MVC4 with Bootstrap Styling Enabled

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view in MVC that has 2 Razor dropdownlistfor's on it.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, new SelectList(Model.CustomerList, "Id", "Name", @Model.CustomerId), 
new { @class = "bs-select form-control input-large", data_style = "btn-primary", id = "ddlCustomer", onchange = "reloadDdl()" })
```

and:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BranchId, new SelectList(Model.BranchList, "Id", "Description", @Model.BranchId),
new { @class = "bs-select form-control input-large", data_style = "btn-primary", id = "ddlBranch" })
```

When the first Dropdownlist selection changes, the second dropdown loads in a new set of options.  For example, if the Customer Dropdown has "a" selected, the branch dropdown will have "1", "2", "3" available for selection.  If you change the Customer dropdown selection to "b", the branch dropdown changes to "4", "5", "6".  This is being achieved through an ajax call to my controller using the following code:

```
function reloadDdl(){
    var customerId =  $("#ddlCustomer").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Adjuster/RefreshAddEditView',
        data: { CustomerId: customerId },
        method: 'POST',
        success: function (result){
            var mySelect = $('#ddlBranch');
            mySelect.find('option').remove().end();
            for(var i = 0; i<result.branchList.length;i++){
                mySelect.append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(result.branchList[i]["Id"]).html(result.branchList[i]["Description"])
                );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The issue I am running into is that the Razor dropdown is a normal select tag with options inside of it:

```
<select class="bs-select form-control input-large" data-style="btn-primary" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field BranchId must be a number." data-val-required="The BranchId field is required." id="ddlBranch" name="BranchId">
```

But when the Bootstrap Javascript

```
ComponentsDropdowns.init();
```

is applied, it turns into a button with a span and unordered list.

If anyone knows a solution either by changing how I am repopulating the dropdownlist, or how I could work around Bootstrap, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Assuming your referring to [Bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) then use `$('#ddlBranch').selectpicker('refresh');`

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple jquery instead of making an ajax call like

```
$("#fotype").change(function () {

    if ($('#fotype').find(":selected").val() == 1) {
        $("#wd option[value='1']").show();
        $("#wd option[value='2']").hide();
        $("#wd option[value='3']").show();
        $("#wd option[value='4']").show();
        $("#wd option[value='5']").hide();
        $("#wd option[value='6']").show();
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working as intended by changing the success result of my ajax call.  Here is what it looks like now:

```
function reloadDdl(){
        $.ajax({
        url: '/Adjuster/RefreshAddEditView',
        data: { CustomerId: $("#ddlCustomer").val() },
        method: 'POST',
        success: function (result){
            $("#BranchList").empty();
            $("#BranchList").append($('<select></select>').attr("id", "ddlBranch"))

            for(var i = 0; i < result.branchList.length;i++){
                $("#ddlBranch").append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(result.branchList[i]["Id"]).html(result.branchList[i]["Description"])
                );
            }
            $("#ddlBranch").addClass("bs-select").addClass("form-control").addClass("input-large").data("style", "btn-primary").attr("name", "BranchId").selectpicker();
        }
    });
}
```

I wrapped the Razor dropdown in a div as well like this:

```
<div id="BranchList">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BranchId, new SelectList(Model.BranchList, "Id", "Description", @Model.BranchId),
new { @class = "bs-select form-control input-large", data_style = "btn-primary", id = "ddlBranch" })
</div>
```

Comment: Your dropdownlist already has those classes and attributes added (completely pointless adding them again) and if your had already applied `.selectpicker()` then you should not be doing it again (unless you destroy the first). All that's necessary is to replace the last line with `$('#ddlBranch').selectpicker('refresh');`